# Cant apply CSS elements to make form right-aligned

Tags: html, css

i have basic html form with css elements and i can't figure out why CSS code is not applied and does nothing. There is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <title> A basic form </title>
      <style type ="text/css">

      .form-field{
          clear: both;
          padding: 10px;
          width: 350px;
      }

      .form-field label{

          float: left;
          width: 450px;
          text-align: right;
          font-size: xx-small;
      }

      .form-field input{

          float: right;
          width: 150px;
          text-align: ;
      }

      #submit{


          font-size: larger;
          text-align: center;
      }


      </style>

      </head>

      <body>
      <h1> A basic form </h1>
      <hr> 
      <form action="#">
      <fieldset >
        <legend>Form Information </legend>
        <div> 
            <label for="username"> Name :</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        </div>
        <div>
        <label form="email"> E-mail address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="email">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit"
            value="Send Form">
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear Form">
        </div>

      </fieldset>
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>
```

In fact, it does make changes for my submit button, but form itself is still have base (left) alignment. What did i miss?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: tried to give your fields some `id` or `class` tag too?

Comment: Where is your class .form-field?

Comment: No i didn't. Class is not declared, there is whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it for you.  [**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9UAZg/)

```
fieldset {text-align:right;}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have edited your html.
Please take a look [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9kKd/)

I have just added

```
<fieldset class="form-field">
```

Comment: I don't feel the output generated by your fiddle looks like a "finished product"

Answer (score 3):

Your style is for class "form-field" but it is not mentioned anywhere in the html code.

Edit your form tag to -

```
<form action="#" class="form-field">
```

Then you will be able to see the change.

Answer (score 2):

Make the form like this:

```
<form class="form" action="#">
```

Add this css:-

```
.form{
     text-align: right;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSS code is not applied because the HTML element with the class "form-field" that you try to style doesn't exists. You need to apply the class to a parent element in order to be able to style the label and input.